# How can I modify all comments in git repository?

Tags: git, version-control, repository

I have managed a my project using git.
But I must published this repository, so I have to modify all comments and author names of git repo, because I can't publish some comments and author name.

My git repo has 99 commits and is synced remote repository.
There are a lot of committing points in using git rebase -i.

How can I modify comments and author names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are after `git filter-branch`. With it you can easily change committer names, author names and commit messages throughout the whole history. But be aware that this changes all SHA1 values, so if someone has cloned that repository and based work off of it, he has to manually rebase all his branches onto the new history.

Comment: I know how to modify author name, but I don't know how to modify comments.

Comment: With `--msg-filter`